# Should max(A,B) always return A or B?

Tags: glsl, webgl, google-chrome-os

In my GLSL program, I have a function that checks, if each component of vec2 is between 0 and 1:

```
bool in01(vec2 c) { 
    return max(vec2(0.0,0.0), min(vec2(1.0,1.0), c)) == c; 
}
```

It works very well on many devices, until I tried it on  Acer Chromebook R13 with MediaTek M8173C (in WebGL in a browser). On that device, it seems like max(A,B) can return a value, which is neither A or B. So I fixed it by using `<=` instead of max/min.

But still, I am curious, why did it happen. Was it my fault (GLSL spec does not require max() to return one of input values), or it is a bug in the device environment (but then, how could it pass all the test and get into production)?

Answer (score 4):

Functions that take vectors will do *element-wise* operations on them, returning a vector where each pair of elements has had that operation done on them. If you do `sin(some_vector)`, the returned vector has `sin` done on each of its elements.

You cannot put vectors in an order; there is no concept of a vector which is greater or less than another. You *can* compare their elements. Which is exactly what `max` and `min` do: they do element-wise comparison, and return the max/min *elements*.

So the resulting vector is very much *not* guaranteed to be one of the parameters. However, the elements of the resulting vector *are required* to be one of the corresponding elements of the vector passed in. So it can't make up values.

And BTW, the function you're clearly looking for is `clamp`.

---

That being said, it is possible that this is a numeric precision issue. I'm not sure how, since you're not storing the value in a variable, but the temporaries that this expression uses could cause the resulting elements of `c` to have slightly different values than what was passed in.

Thus, using `clamp` might clear this up. Then again, it might not. It would be better to just ask the question you're looking for directly:

```
return (any(lessThan(vec2(0.0, 0.0), c) || (any(greaterThan(1.0, 1.0), c);
```

I don't know if GLSL ES 1.00 or WebGL's shaders have `any` and `less/greaterThan`. But this works on desktop GL.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that max() works component-wise. And I know, that there are 200 other ways to do it. But my original function in01 is written in the right way, right? That is exactly what I want to know, if GLSL is allowed to do that, or not.

Comment: @IvanKuckir: You're doing floating-point equality tests. That's *always* a potential problem.

Comment: You can not just say "it is a bad idea to do this". You should show some proof, why is it bad (e.g. a link to spec.). I understand, that 3*(1/3) may not be equal to 1 in float arithmetics. But I expected max / min to be precise (and simply compare values).

Comment: @IvanKuckir: But it *doesn't* just "compare values". By definition it must *return them*. Which means that, at some point, there are two copies of a value in memory. So show me the part of the GLSL specification that ensures that two copies of a floating-point value must compare equal. Also, the spec is a PDF; I cannot link you to part of a PDF.

Comment: "Two copies of a float value must compare equal" - Well, if two floats (not NaNs) have exactly the same bits (ones and zeros), I expect the == operator to be true, no matter if it is GLSL or any other language.